# Adding a line in XML with a space

Tags: xml, powershell

I have that XML

```
    <application>
  <component name="UpdatesConfigurable">    
    <enabledExternalComponentSources>
      <item value="Android SDK" />
    </enabledExternalComponentSources>
    <option name="externalUpdateChannels">
      <map>
        <entry key="Android SDK" value="Stable Channel" />
      </map>
    </option>
    <knownExternalComponentSources>
      <item value="Android SDK" />
    </knownExternalComponentSources>
    <option name="LAST_BUILD_CHECKED" value="IU-202.7660.26" />
    <option name="LAST_TIME_CHECKED" value="1606406082514" />
  </component>
</application>
```

I need to add

```
<option name="CHECK_NEEDED" value="false" />
```

Then getting:

```
    <application>
  <component name="UpdatesConfigurable">
    <option name="CHECK_NEEDED" value="false" />
    <enabledExternalComponentSources>
      <item value="Android SDK" />
    </enabledExternalComponentSources>
    <option name="externalUpdateChannels">
      <map>
        <entry key="Android SDK" value="Stable Channel" />
      </map>
    </option>
    <knownExternalComponentSources>
      <item value="Android SDK" />
    </knownExternalComponentSources>
    <option name="LAST_BUILD_CHECKED" value="IU-202.7660.26" />
    <option name="LAST_TIME_CHECKED" value="1606406082514" />
  </component>
</application>
```

I  created that script:

```
    $fileName = “C:\sovgarde\updates.xml”;
$xml = [System.Xml.XmlDocument](Get-Content $fileName);

$child = $xml.CreateElement('option name')
$child.SetAttribute('CHECK_NEEDED','false')
$node = $xml.SelectSingleNode('component name')
$node.AppendChild($child)
```

But getting a failure at "option name"...

How adding that line if its not already existing. I believe the issue is in the space.

Thanks,

Comment: It is better to use XSLT and its so called **Identity Transform** for your task.

Comment: Your code tries to create an element named 'option name', but the actual element is named just 'option'. Spaces are not allowed in XML element names, so 'name' actually is the first attribute. You have to set two attributes.

Comment: zett42 I am not sure to understand. How would I set a second attribute and then storing the right information on that line?

Comment: Yitzhak Khabinsky Do you have an exemple?

Comment: http://www.usingxml.com/Transforms/XslIdentity

Comment: Yitzhak Khabinsky Seems  I am dumb... I really don't understand. I have no control on this XML so I need adding a single line if its not existing :(

Comment: Yitzhak Khabinsky I have no control on that XML so I can't see how adding a single line to that XML with your suggestion.

Comment: @FrançoisRacine, I added XSLT Fiddle to my answer to demonstrate how it works.

Answer (score 1):

The element name is `option`, not `option name`.

You need to create an element named `option` and then you want to create two attributes. One named `name` with the value "CHECK_NEEDED" and another attribute named `check` with the value "false"

```
$fileName = “C:\sovgarde\updates.xml”;
$xml = [System.Xml.XmlDocument](Get-Content $fileName);

$child = $xml.CreateElement('option')
$child.SetAttribute('name', 'CHECK_NEEDED')
$child.SetAttribute('check','false')
$node = $xml.SelectSingleNode('component')
$node.AppendChild($child)
```

Comment: This is interesting what about the "SelectSingleNode" the space is still making failing.

Comment: Same applies, the element name is `component`, so remove " name" from that. Sorry about that, I hadn't run the code to spot the issue and had missed it.

Comment: 1. Null value error. and how saving the xml change at the end?

Comment: $node = $xml.SelectSingleNode('component') is returning a Null value error. and how saving the xml change at the end?

Comment: Sound this may be working but how saving ithe xml t to confirm if its working 
$node = $xml.SelectSingleNode('//component')

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument.save?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 0):

Here is your **Identity Transform** XSLT.

It works in a very simple and powerful way.
It will copy the input XML as-is. But when it gets to the `<enabledExternalComponentSources>` element, it will add a new element

`<option name="CHECK_NEEDED" value="false" />` to a proper location. Which is exactly what you need.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

   <!-- IdentityTransform -->
   <xsl:template match="/ | @* | node()">
         <xsl:copy>
               <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
         </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
   
   <xsl:template match="enabledExternalComponentSources">
        <option name="CHECK_NEEDED" value="false" />
         <xsl:copy>
               <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
         </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>   

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

To see what it does: [XSLT Fiddle](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/93nwMod/1)

[Simple Powershell script for XSLT](http://web.pdx.edu/%7Ei1kc/programming/powershell/powershellXSLT.html)

Comment: How are you applying the XSLT with Powershell? So If I understand correctly it is like a Windows installer MST?!

Answer (score 0):

This will be working:

```
$fileName = “C:\sovgarde\updates.xml”;
$xml = [System.Xml.XmlDocument](Get-Content $fileName);

$child = $xml.CreateElement('option')
$child.SetAttribute('name', 'CHECK_NEEDED')
$child.SetAttribute('value','false')
$node = $xml.SelectSingleNode('//component')
$node.AppendChild($child)
$node
$xml.Save($fileName)
```

Now I am trying to remove the attribute check_needed and it is not working

```
   $fileName = “C:\sovgarde\updates.xml”;
$xml = [System.Xml.XmlDocument](Get-Content $fileName);

$child = $xml.CreateElement('option')
$child.SetAttribute('name', 'CHECK_NEEDED')
$child.SetAttribute('value','false')
If ($xml.application.component.option.name -icontains "CHECK_NEEDED") {
    
    $node = $xml.SelectSingleNode('//component')
    $node.RemoveAttribute('CHECK_NEEDED') 
    $xml.Save($fileName)   
    
}
```

The detection is working correctly but after the save the value is still existing.